# Inserting Danish characters to sql server from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When inserting danish characters to sql server to a field with an nvarchar datatype the danish characters get malformed. Example: brændstof is converted to brÃ¦ndstof. When it is directly from sql server query window it is working correctly. I tried giving different collations to that field(Latin1_Genaral,Danish_Greenlandic_100_CI_AI,Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI etc.)  Is there a way to achieve this. I am using [Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=20098). Please help

Comment: This sounds like a regular utf8/unicode problem. I only use MySQL myself, but I'm sure you can specify the *collation* (character set) of a row in MySQL as well. [Here's a guide on all the steps in MySQL/PHP to go through to make sure everything is the correct character set - I'm sure you could use some of this info for MSSQL](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/08/31/solving-php-mysql-utf-8-issues/)

Comment: nitpickery, but "collation" is not the same as a charset.

Comment: Please clarify this vague but critical sentence: ` When it is directly from sql server query window it is working correctly.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a work around, just html encoded the danish string before insering into table, and when displaying just decoded back

Answer (score 2):

instead of a literal 'æ', use its CHAR equivalent and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

I don't now what about Danish letters, but I had problem with Armenian in SQL SERVER. I solved this problem like this.

```
insert into sometable(field) values( N'myArmenianText' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as guess here:

I think the problem is in the PHP part, not in the MySQL part (I read you used some encoding for that field specifically for Danish). Or even earlier. Ever tried to put an 'ä' on an HTML page (the real character, not `&auml;`)? It gets converted to some other chars like the example in your question. So I see two possibilities here:

- User input is incorrectly URl-encoded
- PHP uses some encoding that doesn't support Danish characters.

Or perhaps 3 & 4 (less likely):

- The char arrives incorrectly at the client (if you resend some chars to the server I don't know if that's the case)
- The user agent converts the chars and thus sends malformed chars to the server (or displays them wrong, which would mean the right chars are on the server, but you can't view them with your browser)